# How to use a section of an array without ever printing/showing that array?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-finance

I am using a function in Google Sheets that outputs a 2 column array. I want to use data from only the second column of that array to calculate a figure. But I would like to do this all in a single cell and do not want to have to output the array, and then use a separate cell to calculate from the figures in that array.

I can already get the output I need by pasting the array on another sheet within the same spreadsheet, but this is a messy solution.

This is the function I am using:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("eurusd","close","6/1/2019","6/13/2019")
```

It outputs the date and price data in a 2x13 array
I want to use the second column of that array (less the heading) to sum and divide by 12 to take an average of the closing rates over that period. But I would like to do it all in a single cell without having to see the array.

I want to use the second column of that array (less the heading) to sum and divide by 12 to take an average of the closing rates over that period. But I would like to do it all in a single cell without having to ever see the array.

Answer (score 0):

to isolate it you can do this:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("EURUSD", "close", "1/6/2019", "13/6/2019"), 
 "select Col2 offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

and then just average it like:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("EURUSD", "close", "1/6/2019", "13/6/2019"), 
 "select Col2 offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]